# Does tensorflow work on python3.9 or not?

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.9 and I try a lot of commands in cmd to install TensorFlow but it always gives me (ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TensorFlow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for TensorFlow)
Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow hasn't released anything for python3.9 . Please use a python virtual environment with an old version of python to run Tensorflow.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44416#issuecomment-720666510

Comment: I installed python3.8 and still got the error?

Comment: Are you sure that you switched to Python 3.8 after installing? Check by running "Python3 --version" in your terminal/command prompt

Comment: @SarahMuhammed ^

Comment: it's great how brew overwrites python3 with a link to python3.9 after installing both 3.9 and 3.9, thus breaking tensorflow... /s